# Endless adapter onclick event

Tags: android, adapter, android-listfragment

I'm trying to use the endless adapter in a list fragment context. 
Everything is working pretty fine except for the click events on any of the item.

- If the fragment is implementing onclicklistener, nothing happens in onclick
- If the fragment is implementing onitemclicklistener, nothing happens in onitemclick
- If I override onListItemclick, I never get any response.
- Adding an "android:onClick" in the item xml layout, crash the app with a "can't found your public void thing(View v) function in android.app.Application" (don't knwo why it's not looking in my fragment or my activity where  I tried to declare it).

I ended making a setClickListener in the endless adapter. But the event is intercepted in the endless adapter and I must propagage it to my fragment which makes this solution really ugly.

Any hint ?

Comment: If you get rid of `EndlessAdapter`, you will likely see that your problems still exist, demonstrating that it is not an issue with `EndlessAdapter`. If you feel that you can demonstrate that this is a problem unique to `EndlessAdapter`, create a sample project that reproduces that error, upload the project somewhere, and file an issue on the `EndlessAdapter` repo: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless

Comment: I understand your point. I believe too that this is not a endlessadapter issue but a list fragment one. It's just that this is the context. Any hint about adding event handling in this case? thnaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it...

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        }
    });
}
```